# Permissions and Privilege Oracle DB User for Sonar LTS

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I try to install SonarQube LTS with Oracle and I´m needing know the Best recomendations on permissions and privilege  for user Sonar on DB Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what [the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server) say (emphasis added):

> Create an empty schema and a sonarqube user. **Grant this sonarqube user permissions to create, update and delete objects for this schema**. The charset of the database has to be set to "UTF-8" and the language (database and user) to "English".